# Run Intel Core i5 apps in Intel Celeron processor

Tags: emulator

I want to emulate things like AVX instruction set used in Intel Core processors. My laptop processor is an Intel Celeron.

I'm aware of [Intel SDE](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/software-development-emulator.html), is there anything else?

Comment: Instead of searching for a emulator you should simply rent a cloud server that has the necessary instruction set or get yourself a better computer. That will be of more use to you if you want to run a specific software.

Comment: @Robert I'd like to play a game (Phantasy Star Online 2: New Genesis). Since I don't want to buy a new PC right now, is there a cloud server appropriate for that?

Comment: So you have a low end CPU and you were looking for an emulation which makes everything even slower and they you want to play a game on it? Check out online game servers which stream the display to you like GeForce Now or similar. Not sure if they support that game.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I was aware of services like Xbox Game Pass and GeForce Now, but I've not found the PSO2 game anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [Shadow platform](https://shadow.tech). In my case, it is said that it can run the game Final Fantasy XIV ([reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffxiv/comments/le0he7/ffxiv_cloud_gaming/)), so I believe PSO2 (the game I want to play) is also supported by it.

The only issue is that the cost is quite expensive for me and it isn't available in my region.